# How to update array items by multiplying with other items in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

The result I want to get is Multiply the index value with other index value. e.g in the code below:
i want to update arr[0] value by arr[0]*arr[1], arr[9] value by arr[9]*arr[9-8] and for remaining indexes it'll be arr[i-1] * arr[i] * arr[i+1]. It is working fine on first index but at other indexes I am getting unexpected result.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, j, k;
    
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        if(j == 0){
            arr[j] = arr[j] * arr[j + 1];
        }else if(j == 9){
            arr[j] = arr[j] * arr[j - 1];
        }else{
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1] * arr[j] * arr[j + 1];
        }
    }
    
    for(k = 0; k < 10; k++){
        cout<<arr[k]<<" ";
    }
}
```

---

**Output:** 2 12 144 2880 86400 3628800 203212800 1746419712 -1736015872 -180289536

**Expected Result:** 2 6 24 60 120 210 336 504 720 90

Comment: The numbers get bigger and bigger and overflow at one point. If you print the whole array in each iteration you will see it.

Comment: What would be your *expected* result

Comment: Please describe why the output is unexpected. 2 = 1*2, 12 = 2 * 2 * 3, 144 = 12 * 3 * 4, 2880 = 12 * 144 * 5, .... That's what I expect.

Comment: Expected Result: 2 6 24 60 120 210 336 504 720 90

Comment: You're changing the values in the array and using the new values to calculate the next values. You need a copy of your array.

Comment: How can i do that? Kindly explain what is happening now? And what to do for expected result?

Comment: In the first step you change the first element from 1 to 2. In the next step you use this new value. Your array at the beginning is {1, 2, 3, ...}. After the first step the array is {2, 2, 3, ...} and 2 * 2 * 3 = 12 is the second result. You can solve the problem by storing the results in a separate array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store the results in a separate array or else you overwrite the values in the same array you use for future calculations.

In your case, when `j == 0` you do:

```
arr[0] = arr[0] * arr[1]; // 1 * 2 = 2
```

So `arr[0]` is now `2`. You then do

```
arr[1] = arr[0] * arr[1] * arr[2]; // 2 * 2 * 3 = 12, not 1 * 2 * 3 = 6
```

...and so on. If you instead store the result in a separate array, that problem goes away. Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// using namespace std; // Don't use this.

int main(){
    int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int res[10] = {0};
    
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (j == 0)
            res[j] = arr[j] * arr[j + 1];
        else if (j == 9)
            res[j] = arr[j] * arr[j - 1];
        else
            res[j] = arr[j - 1] * arr[j] * arr[j + 1];
    }
    
    for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        std::cout << res[k] << ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
2 6 24 60 120 210 336 504 720 90
```

Comment: Let me know why should we not use using (namespace std). It occurs any problem?

Comment: @Shakir Sure, here's a collection of reasons: [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Shakir Did you understand the reason for what is happening in your program? Please ask if I need to clarify it further.

Comment: I just got it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. I've got my answer that why we should not use **using namespace std**. But I don't think it'll create problem in such a small program. What do you say?

Comment: @Shakir It only creates problems for people reading the program. If I see `std::cout` I rarely have to worry. If I see `cout` it could be just about any `cout`. Also, in this small program the benefit one gets from `using namespace std;` is completely lost, since you only do one `std::cout` - so you actually typed in more characters to avoid having to type `std::` later. It's best just to forget about `using namespace std;` - at least for now.

Comment: @Shakir I've already seen about 20 questions on Stack Overflow describing different problems caused by `using namespace std;`. If you don't know all the names that are imported by that namespace you shouldn't use it. After `using namespace std;` you shouldn't use names like `begin`, `end`, `data`, `swap`, `array`, `vector`, `list`, ... for your functions or variables because they are already in use.